# How to detect if user input have one word only in Watson Assistant?

Tags: chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, spring-el

I am using the IBM Watson Conversation Assistant Chatbot. 
I am having troubles finding in the documentation how to detect if the user input consists of a single word. It's fine for simplicity and for my goal to use the presence of spaces as surrogate (no spaces means only word).

I tried using SpEL.
I tried also to intercept the following as Node entry:

```
request.input.text:" "
```

with scarce results.

What should I write into the "If assistant recognizes:" field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how I solved, hopefully will save a lot of time to someone else.

Inside the node, under "If assistant recognizes:"

```
!input.text.contains(' ')
```

Then respond with:

```
You wrote  "<? input.text ?>". Please write full sentences.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the JavaScript DOM element to read the inner text and manipulate it.

Comment: Thanks Mahesh, but my question is about IBM-Watson and SpEL.